# How to use parameter of a function as default value of its optional paramterer in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, parameters, optional-parameters

How can I use the value from a functions parameter as the default value of an optional parameter in VB.net?

This doesn't work for me:

```
Public Function func(ByVal param1 As String, ByVal param2 As String, ByVal Optional param3 As String = param1) As String
   Return ""
End Function
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/optional-parameters) for `Optional` parameters for why this won't work:

> - Every optional parameter in the procedure definition must specify a default value.
> - The default value for an optional parameter must be a **constant expression**.
> - Every parameter following an optional parameter in the procedure definition must also be optional.

Therefore, you would need something like this to work as you intended:

```
Function func(ByVal param1 As String, ByVal param2 As String, ByVal Optional param3 As String = "") As String
    If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(param3) Then
        param3 = param1
    End If

    Return ""
End Function
```

However, you could solve this with an overload instead of `Optional`:

```
Function func(ByVal param1 As String, ByVal param2 As String) As String
    Return func(param1, param2, param1)
End Function

Function func(ByVal param1 As String, ByVal param2 As String, ByVal param3 as String) As String
    Return ""
End Function
```

Probably not the clearest implementation though, so if you do this make sure to add in XML commenting to the method so usage is easily understood.